# boost asio socket exits after sending some msgs

Tags: c++

when i connect via telnet to it it's giving me "Connection lost to host" after i receive some msgs then exits, what's wrong? you can review the code here:
http://textuallircserver.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/client.cpp
any help is apperciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message "Connection lost to host" sounds like if a firewall were closing the connection down. Can you try telnet via command line and check the output?

Comment: Yeah, that's what im using ;s